# Javascript/jQuery - adding value to integer changes other variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm experiencing something weird with a piece of code I've written to enlarge a link as soon as the user scrolls past a div box. I'm using this code:

```
function resize_links() {
    $(".all_planes a").css({fontSize: "16px"})
    $( ".plane_container" ).each(function( ) {
        var offtop = $(this).offset().top;
        var scrolltop = $(window).scrollTop();

        var type = $(this).data("type");

        if(scrolltop > offtop) {
            if (window.console) console.log(scrolltop + " " + offtop + " " + type);

            $("." + type + "_link").css({
                fontSize: "20px"
            });
        }
    });
}
$( window ).scroll(function() {
    resize_links();
});
```

The above function works but the illogical things happen as soon as I add some pixels to the `scrolltop` variable (`scrolltop = scrolltop + 98`) to account for a fixed header I have on my website. By looking at the console I see that in this case, the values of `scrolltop` and `offtop` are identical. Without the 98, `offtop` is a constant value as it logically should be.
I tried to substract a value from `scrolltop` to find out if that makes a difference and surprisingly everything works as it should that way. 
I've also deactivated other JS code to check if there was something interfering but I couldn't find a solution this way either.
What is probably worth noting is that the `.plane_container` divs are loaded onto the site using the jQuery `.html()` method.
Code:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    var startupcont = $(".skyline_cont").html();
    $(".sky_go_switch").html(startupcont);   
});
```

So there are pretty weird things going somehow and if there are more things that you need to see to get an idea of the issue then I will of course add this to my question. Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**
Basically this is what I am trying to achieve: https://jsfiddle.net/xs5rov25/

**Edit 2:**
I'm somehow stuck here and nothing really seems to make sense. As soon as I add any value to `scrolltop`, the `offtop` value goes wild.
But I may have found a hint: if I leave out the dynamic loading stuff and just post the contents directly into the `.sky_go_switch` div, my code works fine - even with the 98 added. 
Is there maybe a different way to manage the dynamic loading (The user can control which content is displayed - there are two options - see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1Lret7vk/4/)? Or is there a way to change my current resize_links code so that it works in my situation?

**Edit 3:**
**Okay, so I was finally able to recreate the issue in my fiddle. I have merged the two fiddles I created and now you can see the problem.**
Without the 98 - working version: https://jsfiddle.net/a5jxw2jd/
Adding the 98 - the crazy things start to happen: https://jsfiddle.net/72jkfxkw/
You can see that all links resize at once with the first scroll in the second fiddle. This is due to the fact that `scrolltop` is somehow identical to `offtop` then (see console).

Comment: Please keep in mind that + might try to concatenate. try `scrolltop = +scrolltop + 98;`. Can you please provide us a fiddle of the current code?

Comment: Adding a plus in front of scrolltop unfortunately didn't work. And I added the fiddle to the question.

Comment: Where do you add `scrollTop = scrollTop + 98`? Works fine when I tried it in your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xs5rov25/1/

Comment: Just realized that, too! The problem probably has to do with something else. See my edit3. I could now recreate the exact issue. Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't really explain why (because I would imagine your fiddle without the + 98 should have the same problem), but I do know you can fix it by making your box selector only work for the visible boxes by changing the selector from just ".box" to ".switcher_content .box". I guess it has something to do with the fact that offset positions of invisible elements give weird results, and since you're updating all the #_link elements for each .box evaluated, the invisible ones overwrite the correct value of the visible box.
But like I said, I have no explanation why the same isn't happening in the version without + 98...

Comment: This is a correct answer, use `.box:visible` as a selector, because hidden elements testing overwrites testing of visible boxes. You should also optimize your code, take a look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/72jkfxkw/3/).

Comment: The answer works great - thanks! And also thanks for the optimization advice!